# Colorings of another curious graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I am here again to ask about chromatic polynomials and number of colorings of a curious graph. I have been making several questions of this topic since I have an evaluation within some days and I just want to make sure I do my best.

In this case, since I still don't know how to put an image here, the most I can do is to explain the graph. The graph $G$ is a graph of $n+2$ vertices, with $n$ vertices forming a $n$-cycle. The two remaining vertex are in the center of the graph, inside the cycle. Each of these two vertices are connected to all of the vertices of the cycle, but they are not connected with each other. I am asked to find how many colorings are there using the colours $\{a_1 \dots a_k \}$. Here is my attempt:

I choose first the colors of the "central"-vertices: there are $k$ options for the first and another $k$ options for the second one they are not connected with each other. However, due to the connections I explained above, each vertex of the $n$-cycle can't use any of the colors used before, therefore I separated the problem now in two cases:

a) The central vertices have the same colour $\Rightarrow$ there are still $k-1$ colours to use for the cycle, and then here appears the chromatico polynomial of the cycle using $k-1$ colours: $P_{C_{n}}(k-1)$. And since the central vertices have the same colour, there are $k$ possible colors.

b) The central vertices have different colours $\Rightarrow$ there are still $k-2$ colours to use, then here appears $P_{C_n}(k-2)$. Due to the fact that the central vertices have different colors, there are $k(k-1)$ possibilities to choose them.

Then, the answer would be that there are $k\cdot P_{C_n}(k-1) + k(k-1)\cdot P_{C_n}(k-2)$ possible colorings. This would be my final answer, but I am under the impression something isn't ok. Am I right with my answer?

Comment: The answer looks correct to me.